# Javascript array push subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays

Each `newdata[x][0]]` looks like this -> `[95, 152, 174, 197, 261]`
but when I do `newgooddata.push([newdata[x][0]])` twice (x=0 and 1)
I get [image: NEWDATA]

I want it to be:

[image: THE STRUCTURE I WANT]

I seem to be adding them wrong. Some help , with an explanation?

Comment: [mdn array docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are putting `newdata[x][0]` into an array before pushing.

```
newgooddata.push([newdata[x][0]])  // bad

newgooddata.push(newdata[x][0])    // good
```

The extra `[]` around `newdata[x][0]` creates a new array containing one element: `newdata[x][0]`.